# Stop JQuery Mobile from hiding url parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

If an anchor exists with this link `http://localhost:8888/#view_trend?id=147&title=prague-test-trend-sep-30`

When clicked, only `http://localhost:8888/#view_trend` is seen in the browser.

Since I use `location.href` to get the link info, i need to see the full link with the parameters when the link is opened.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: //localhost:8888/?id=147&title=prague-test-trend-sep-30#view_trend ?

Comment: Nop. Still doesn't show :(

Comment: If you're still struggling with this, I recently created and released a [plug-in](https://github.com/CameronAskew/jquery.mobile.paramsHandler) which may help you out.

Answer (score 0):

I assume #view_trend is an internal page (DIV with data-role of page).  If so, why use query string parameters? Can you not just use Javascript variables within the page, or even the Data attribute of the page div to store your id and title?

If you do want to use the url query string, here a fiddle showing ONE of the ways it could be done http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/L77u2/

Basically, use the click event of the link to parse the query string and save to the data attrib of the view_trend page, then in pagebeforeshow on view_trend, retrieve these params:

```
$('#linkTrend').on("click", function () {
    var l = $(this).attr("href");
    l = l.substring(l.indexOf('?') + 1);
    var qs = getUrlVars(l);
    $('#view_trend').data("urlqs", qs);
});

$('#view_trend').on('pagebeforeshow', function () {
    var qs = $(this).data("urlqs");
    var id = qs["id"];
    var title = qs["title"];
    $('#vtrend').html('trend view for id of  ' + id + ' with title of  ' + title);
});

function getUrlVars(url) {
    var vars = [],
    hash;
    var hashes = url.split('&');
    for (var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++) {
      hash = hashes[i].split('=');
      vars.push(hash[0]);
      vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
  }
  return vars;
}
```

Comment: Hi Ezanker. I did something similar to this at first, however, imagine you click on the link. Everything is fine, then you refresh the page, my script has no way of getting the extra parameters.

Comment: I see what you are saying. I guess you could store the last id/title in a LocalStorage or a cookie... [http://amplifyjs.com/api/store/](http://amplifyjs.com/api/store/)